# How can download jar file for Graph class by java

Tags: java

user:2891664 (Radiodef) post java code in  ans to 
http://cn.voidcc.com/question/p-qhrrifyf-bhp.html 
and im not find type of import for `Graph class` as example

> (Graph.vMap.get(Graph.getEdges())

What is jar file for this class

Im need to run Graph java class

```
Shape s = new Line2D.Double(Graph.vMap.get(Graph.getEdges()[i].i1).x;
```

> Graph class not found

Comment: You want to format your code a bit and from the description, it doesn't really clear what is the problem that you have.

Comment: Not a standard JRE class, so probably belongs to that example, project.

Comment: Error in Graph class in the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019132/trying-to-draw-lines-based-on-doubles-but-nothing-shows

Comment: Dear Andrei Sfat , Can please read this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019132/trying-to-draw-lines-based-on-doubles-but-nothing-shows

Comment: Im using Eclipse Error in Grapth class

Comment: Graph.vMap.get(Graph.getEdges()[i].i1).x //error in Graph not found
Graph.vMap.get(Graph.getEdges()[i].i1).y